# Is "there's no sin on you" standard?

Tags: religion

In some translations of the Holy Quran, the following translation comes up:

> And if you decide on a foster suckling-mother for your children, *there is no sin on you*, provided you pay (the mother) what you agreed (to give her) on reasonable basis.

- *Emphasis is mine.*

I wonder if this usage of *sin* is common in contemporary English.

Comment: No, not common, but it is not unheard of.  Rare as it is, you might hear one person say to another person before they embark on a risky mission together, "Hey, if this mission goes south, it's all on you!"  Meaning:  YOU bear the blame if things go badly.  On the other hand, if one person were to say to the other, "Hey, I know this mission is all my idea, and since you are not keen on joining me in it, if it all goes south there is no sin on you; it's all on me."  Meaning:  You won't bear the sin if things go badly; I will (Edwin Ashworth's "burden" metaphor in both examples).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to about a religious interpretation of what a sin is.

Comment: @Skooba The question is about an unfamiliar, possibly nonstandard construction, not a request for a religious opinion. It's not off topic.

Comment: @Skooba The question of on-topicness of jargon is a perennial here, but I think most Anglophones will be aware of the word 'sin', if not 'praseodymium', ''filtrum' or 'chancery'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

The word *sin* is used in two different ways:

> **1. as a non-count noun** (the 'sin-disposition' and almost personification):
>
> Christians believe in original sin.
>
> Sin is fundamentally rebellion against God's rules of conduct, an
>   insistence on one's own way.
>
> **2. as a count noun** (a particular occurrence, or arguably type):
>
> I gave way to the sin of anger yesterday. (arguably in between non-count and count)
>
> Her sins are many.

The count-noun usage may be encountered in statements such as:

> There is not one sin that can be held against you if you are forgiven
>   on the basis of the substitutionary death of Jesus.

The non-count noun usage may be encountered in statements such as:

> Sin will no longer have the hold on you it did before you became a Christian.

Using the preposition *on* here is really using a staining (or burdening) metaphor, and would require the metaphor to be stated more fully:

> She is now washed clean from the stain of sin that was once on her.
>
> The burden of sin on him has now been removed.

And, though contemporary, this type of language is obviously largely confined to the religious domain.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase *there is no sin on you* is a literal translation of the Arabic.

It is understood, but I think in English the most correct way of saying it is to use the verb *incur* with the noun *sin*.

The resulting translation would read:

And if you decide on a foster suckling-mother for your children, **you will incur no sin**, provided you pay (the mother) what you agreed (to give her) on reasonable basis.

Comment: Can we not simply understand "on you" to be a shortening of "on your account"? That would make it analogous with similar statements like "shame on you".